# Android BLE set write characteristics after onServicesDiscovered() or broadcast method after onServicesDiscovered()?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to create the BLE module as follows:

```
Connect -> Discover Service -> Auto Set characteristics -> Send checkSum Bytes
```

If the device cannot receive the bytes within 10 seconds, the bluetooth connection disconnect itself.

When it comes to the practice, it bluetooth connection disconnect itself even I have set the background `Thread` to send the checksum bytes. I have found that it is too difficult to create the Handler message to return the message from the BLuetoothLeService to the `Main Activity` via broadcast. Even I have declared finding the services and hence characteristics right away, there are no responses got before sending the bytes. Would you please tell me which callback method shall the characteristics to be found and set ?

The below is my working:

**DeviceControlActivity.java**

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
        mBluetoothLeService = ((BluetoothLeService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
        if (!mBluetoothLeService.initialize()) {
            Log.e(TAG , "Unable to initialize Bluetooth");
            finish();
        }
        mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
        mBluetoothLeService.setBLEServiceCb(mDCServiceCb);
    }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            mBluetoothLeService = null;
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_STATUS, BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);

            if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = true;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                if(BluetoothLeService.getBtGatt() != null)
                {
                    BluetoothLeService.getBtGatt().discoverServices();
                }
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
                mConnected = false;
                updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                clearUI();
            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
                // Show all the supported services and characteristics on the user interface.
                displayGattServices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
            }
            else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_NOTIFY.equals(action)) {
                // Notification
                byte  [] value = intent.getByteArrayExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
                String uuidStr = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_UUID);
                boolean isFloat = intent.getBooleanExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_FLOAT, false);
                packetLength  = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_LENGTH, 20);
                System.out.println("status B : " + isFloat);
                if(isFloat){
                    onCharacteristicChangedWithParam(uuidStr, value);
                }else{
                    onCharacteristicChanged(uuidStr, value);
                }

            } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_WRITE.equals(action)) {
                // Data written
                String uuidStr = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_UUID);
                onCharacteristicWrite(uuidStr,status);

        } else if (BluetoothLeService.ACTION_DATA_READ.equals(action)) {
            // Data read
            String uuidStr = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_UUID);
            byte  [] value = intent.getByteArrayExtra(BluetoothLeService.EXTRA_DATA);
            onCharacteristicsRead(uuidStr,value,status);
        }
    }
};
```

**BluetoothLeService.java**

```
/**
 * Service for managing connection and data communication with a GATT server hosted on a
 * given Bluetooth LE device. */


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {


    public static BluetoothGatt getBtGatt() {
        return mBluetoothGatt;
    }

    public static BluetoothManager getBtManager() {
        return mThis.mBluetoothManager;
    }

    public static BluetoothLeService getInstance() {
        return mThis;
    }



    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {

            if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
                Log.e(TAG ,  "mBluetoothGatt not created!");
                //  return;
            }
            BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();
            String address = device.getAddress();
            //  Log.d("onConnectionStateChange status = " + status + ", newState = " + newState);
            try {
                switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED, address, status);
                    startReadRssi();
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED, address, status);
                    stopReadRssi();

                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e(TAG ,   "New state not processed: " + newState);
                    break;
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            BluetoothDevice device = gatt.getDevice();

            BluetoothGattService rblService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(U_ABC_SERVICE);
            if (rblService == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "RBL service not found!");
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> Characteristic = rblService
                    .getCharacteristics();

            for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic a : Characteristic) {
                Log.e(TAG, " a =  uuid : " + a.getUuid() + "");
            }



            setReadChar();



            mWriteCharacteristic = rblService.getCharacteristic(U_ABC_W_CHARACTERISTIC);
            if (mWriteCharacteristic == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "RBL TX Characteristic not found!");
                return;
            }

            mCmdCharacteristic  = rblService.getCharacteristic(U_ABC_C_CHARACTERISTIC);
            if (mCmdCharacteristic == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "RBL CMD Characteristic not found!");
                return;
            }
            //  List<BluetoothGattService> gattServices = gatt.getServices();
            /*
            mWriteService = gatt.getService(U_ABC_SERVICE);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mCmdCharacteristic = mWriteService.getCharacteristic(U_ABC_C_CHARACTERISTIC);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setReadChar();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mWriteCharacteristic = mWriteService.getCharacteristic(U_ABC_W_CHARACTERISTIC);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED,    device.getAddress(), status);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            //readCharacteristicQueue.remove();
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_NOTIFY, characteristic ,    BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS);      

        }
```